# Prevent Random Frame Label From Being Selected More Than Once as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The code below does just what I need it to do as far as not selecting a random frame label twice in a row.  However, I need to take it a step further.  Now, I also need to write this code in a way that any random frame that has been selected drops out of the array and is not selected again, period.  Any help with achieving this will be really appreciated. Here is my code:

```
    function getRandomLabel(currentLabel: String): String {
    var labels: Array = ["e1" , "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8" ];
    var currentIndex: int = labels.indexOf(currentLabel);
    if (currentIndex > -1)
        labels.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    var index: Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * labels.length);
    return labels[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy. What you need is to keep the labels outside the function (in your code it is a function local variable and it is repopulated each call) and to extract each one upon request so it is not on the list next time.

```
var labels:Array = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8"];

function getRandomLabel():String
{
    var anIndex:int = Math.random() * labels.length;
    var result:String = labels[anIndex];

    labels.splice(anIndex, 1);
    return result;
}
```